# Error while subsetting dataframe by rows

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe with a 120 observations and 10 variables. I have one line of code for subsetting it to extract only some specific rows

```
  df_reduc_expr <- which(df$Speciestreat != 'Bac + Junc')
  df_reduc <- df[df_reduc_expr,]
```

It was working until it just stoped and started throwing the error

```
Error: Column indexes must be at most 1 if positive, not 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105
```

If I put some numbers after the comma as if I was asking for a subset of columns also, the error stops. But as long I leave the expression for extracting all columns, it appears to get confused with the rows and throws the error.

I don't even know where to start looking for the reason for this behaviour.

Versions:

- Matrix package 1.2-14. The only thing I think could be messing is that I had to install it manually (using RStudio and a .tar.gz), because my version was using 1.2-6 and I needed a newer one for other part of the script. I don't know if it could be affecting.
- RStudio 1.0.136

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add sample data to this question which demonstrates the problem.  I don't see anything wrong, but maybe there is something going on with your data.

Comment: Maybe you could restart RStudio and see if the error goes away.

Comment: RStudio is only an IDE, so the version is irrelevant, and it can't be causing this subsetting bug. However your versions of R and packages like Matrix are very relevant. Did you update any other package? (sometimes they get updated as a dependency of another package)

Comment: **Show us the structure of your dataframe with `dput(df)` or `str(df)`, and also a snippet of reproducible data** (random-seeded data is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting R didn't worked out. But I got to the issue, although I still don't understand what was happening.

The problem was in the original dataframe df. In a previous line, I created a new column and assign some value using

```
df$notransf <- df[, var]
```

Apparently it changed something in the dataframe and it wasn't working well.

I changed it to

```
df["notransf"] <- df[, var]
```

And it returned to normal behaviour.

Just for educational purposes, do you know why this could happen?

**Edit 1. Extra data**

Sorry for not including this from the beggining. The dataframe looks like this

```
Salinity Immersion Speciestreat Species Repetition   Box Soil    `Mean Aboveground length (mm)` Salinity_num Immersion_num Repetition_F notransf
   <fct>    <fct>     <ord>        <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <fct>                            <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
 1 5        0         Bac + Junc   Juncus          1.    2. invaded                          10.4            5.            0. 1               10.4 
 2 5        0         Bac + Junc   Juncus          2.    4. invaded                           6.49           5.            0. 2                6.49
 3 5        0         Bac + Junc   Juncus          3.    6. invaded                          NA              5.            0. 3               NA   
 4 5        0         Bac + Junc   Juncus          4.    8. invaded                           6.21           5.            0. 4                6.21
 5 5        0         Bac + Junc   Juncus          5.   10. invaded                           3.92           5.            0. 5                3.92
 6 5        20        Bac + Junc   Juncus          1.    2. invaded                           6.74           5.           20. 1                6.74
 7 5        20        Bac + Junc   Juncus          2.    4. invaded                           7.10           5.           20. 2                7.10
 8 5        20        Bac + Junc   Juncus          3.    6. invaded                          14.7            5.           20. 3               14.7 
 9 5        20        Bac + Junc   Juncus          4.    8. invaded                           9.77           5.           20. 4                9.77
10 5        20        Bac + Junc   Juncus          5.   10. invaded                           5.77           5.           20. 5                5.77


Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   180 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Salinity                    : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","5","18": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Immersion                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","20","40": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Speciestreat                : Ord.factor w/ 2 levels "Bac + Junc"<"Juncus": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Species                     : chr  "Juncus" "Juncus" "Juncus" "Juncus" ...
 $ Repetition                  : num  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ Box                         : num  2 4 6 8 10 2 4 6 8 10 ...
 $ Soil                        : Factor w/ 2 levels "invaded","recovered": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Mean Aboveground length (mm): num  10.36 6.49 NA 6.21 3.92 ...
 $ Salinity_num                : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Immersion_num               : num  0 0 0 0 0 20 20 20 20 20 ...
 $ Repetition_F                : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ notransf                    : num  10.36 6.49 NA 6.21 3.92 ...
```

And var is a string variable that for this case is

```
var = "Mean Aboveground length (mm)"
```

What I wanted originally was to remove the rows that have the Bac + Junc value in the Speciestreat column.

The usage of the var variable is because further in the code, I need to reference the data to work with, and that sometimes is in one column and sometimes in another one, so I define the var variable with the name of the column a want to analyze, and in the rest of the code just refer to the "notransf" column, knowing it has the data I want in that particular case.

If you need more details let me know.

Comment: If you include your data in the question, someone can most likely explain this

Comment: Please add this extra context to your question, and also a snippet of reproducible data. When you write `<- df[, var]`, I presume <var> is not literal `var`, but a placeholder for some variable name. Literal `var` would be the `stats::var()` variance function, and assigning that to a df column will corrupt your df. (Best not to shadow builtin names). You can show us the structure of your dataframe with `dput(df)` or `str(df)`

Comment: I edited the post with the dataframe characteristics and some extra explanation. Thanks for the feedback.